# Python: Memory issues while trying to copy a file via shell process

Tags: python, out-of-memory, hdfs, popen, file-transfer

I have to copy data from a database and after that i have to upload the file to hdfs.
Initially as the data was huge, i was not able to download the data from database, and was getting Memory Issues.

I have fixed that via using fetchmany() instead of fetchall().

After download, **the file is ~ 0.5GB in size**. Now, I am blocked at the process of copying the file from local machine to hdfs.

Here is the code, i am trying to execute:

```
def run_opt(command):
    logging.info("start execute command: %s" % command)
    out = subprocess.check_output(command, shell = True)
    logging.info("done execute command: %s stdout: %s " % (command, out))
    return out
```

Initially, i was calling following code:

```
def run(command):
    logging.info("start execute command: %s" % command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    logging.info("done execute command: %s stdout: %s stderr: %s" % (command, out, err))
    return out, err
```

But none of them helps.

Exception:

```
 File "/home/allocation/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1235, in _execute_child
   self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What command are you trying to execute?  Do you need the shell?  32-bit or 64-bit?  0.5 Gb is quite a lot to store in memory.

Comment: command : fs -mkdir -p smartcron/2016-12-25 && hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f /tmp/tmprALYsH smartcron/2016-12-25/alpha_user.tsv

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Does that command execute from the command-line without issues?

Comment: With your information provided, the only thing, one can say is, you are using to much memory. Or your system has to few memory to do the task you want. Try not to keep unneeded data in memory.

Comment: @cdarke : Yes, it executes without issues.

Comment: In that case it appears that you are storing too much data in memory before running the command.  Try to free as much as possible.

Comment: this is the way, i am copying data from db to local---->

    with open(tmp_file.name, 'w') as f:
           csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=self.delimiter, quotechar='"')
           for result in self.results_iter(cursor,2000000):
            csv_writer.writerow(result)
           f.flush()
           cursor.close()
           conn.close()
----------------------

Any suggestions for here?